# Multiplication of matrices constructed from transforms gives different result from Multiplication of transforms

Tags: unreal-engine5

```
    FTransform a, b;    
    FMatrix ma = a.ToMatrixWithScale();
    FMatrix mb = b.ToMatrixWithScale();

    FMatrix mc = ma * mb;
    FTransform c1(mc);


    FTransform c2 = a * b;
```

Surprisingly, c1 != c2.

Moreover, for game engine that do not implement Transform (Babylon for example), I can't compose RST to matrix, do the calculation, and decompose it back to RST, because Matrix::operator* is not equivalence of Transform::operator* ?